# Is there a way to show this?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple problem, but have not idea how to deal with it.
Just learning about programming.

The problem is when i use:

```
return {
    redirectUrl:browser.runtime.getURL('/popup.html');,
```

And as it said it redirect me to this url, showing this page.
But i want to show a small pop up instead.

Is there js command to open this page as a window ?
Or open this html as frame one the page ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open Whether it opens a new window or a new tab is not under your control.

Comment: Please provide a better title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a model box. A modal is a dialog box/popup window that is displayed on top of the current page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp